# ASP.NET Button onklick resets label text

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I am developing my first web application. I am trying to get the GPS location and save it for further processing. This is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreatePlace.aspx.cs" Inherits="BeeMaster.CreatePlace" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="background-image:url('images/background.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Create new Place</title>
    <link href="CreatePlace.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #taComment {
            height: 142px;
            width: 339px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="Images/CNP.png" id="logo"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <p id="Comment" style="font-size: large">Click the button to get your position.</p>



        <button onclick="getLocation()" style="font-size: xx-large; width: 380px; height: 50px;">
            Get current location
        </button>
        <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblCoordinates" runat="server"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblLat" runat="server"></asp:Label>,<asp:Label ID="lblLon" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />

        <iframe
            height="600"
            style="border:0"
            id="iFrame">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <form runat="server">
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name:" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:TextBox>
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblNameComment" runat="server" Text="It is recommended to give a name for the place." Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text="Comment:" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <textarea id="taComment" ></textarea>
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentComment" runat="server" Text="Comment specific for the physical place" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <br style="font-size: x-large" />
        <asp:Button ID="btSaveLocation" runat="server" Text="Save current location as new place" OnClick="btSaveLocation_Click" Font-Size="XX-Large" Height="50px" />
    </form>

    <script hidden="hidden">
        var x = document.getElementById("Comment");

        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("lblCoordinates").textContent += "Your location in Coordinates is: ";
            document.getElementById("lblLat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("lblLon").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("iFrame").src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<key>&q=" + latlon + "&maptype=satellite";
            document.getElementById("iFrame").hidden = "";

        }

        function showError(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
            }
        }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the first button, the two labels are getting filled out with the latitude and longitude as they are expected to.
When I click the button "Save current location as new place" it executes the following code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace BeeMaster
{
    public partial class CreatePlace : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btSaveLocation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string lat = lblLat.Text;
            string lon = lblLon.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, there is nothing in the Page_Load function, but still it seems to somehow reset the labels to their inital state because when I debug the application during run time and set a breakpoint at the beginning of the btSaveLocation_Click function then I see that the text of the two labels is blank already.

Does anybody know please what the problem is here?

Thanks

Comment: That's not C! Don't use wrong tags!

Comment: Put values in hidden field as hidden fields values set through JS are accessible in post back

Comment: @Olaf who said something about C? C#!

Comment: @Sami OK, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: @josibu: You did by adding the C tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There were actually two problems:

1. The two labels that I was referring to in the codebehind file were not part of the form, they were in fact outside the form.
2. In the codebehind file I had to request their value in the Page_Load function and not in the function of the button.

This actually solved the problem.

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

The content of a label is not part of a postback and thus will not be updated in the viewstate. Put your values in two hidden fields and use those to  communicate with the server logic.

Comment: So I've now updated the code a little bit as you suggested. But still it does not work. The line `document.getElementById("tbLat").innerText = latlon;` seems to let it crash even because if I put it 2 lines above the lines after it are not getting executed. I tried also do modify textcontent and innerHTML - all the same.

Comment: You should change the value: 
document.getElementById("lblLat").value = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("lblLon").value = position.coords.longitude;

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I couldn't get it work. No matter what I did. But all I actually need is accessing the values I get from the JavaScript in the CodeBehind (C#).

Comment: Sorry. Your javascript should be document.getElementById("tbLat").value = position.coords.latitude; document.getElementById("tbLon").value = position.coords.longitude;

Comment: My problem is not to get the label (or textbox or whatever) displaying the coordinates but rather passing the values to the codeBehind because on PostBack it initializes the page and elements to their default value before it comes to the function requesting the value of the label (or textbox).

Comment: .NET has something called a viewstate. It does not set page elements to their default value unless you do so explicitly. Have you disabled the viewstate somehow?

Comment: Doesn't runat server do basically the same?

Comment: Runat server enables you to manipulate the control from the code behind. The state of the control is saved in the viewstate.

Comment: If you send your entire current code, I can see whats wrong.

Comment: I've now updated the code as it looks (except for the key in the iFrame but it is no critical). Thank you very much for your effort